# Creating an array of bricks for a brick breaker game

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing an assignment which involves coding a brick breaker game in java. There is a gui and 2 enum classes provided. We have to write 4 classes, Level, Paddle, Ball, and Brick. Currently, I am stuck on the Level class. I am trying to output an array of bricks but I am getting a `String index out of range: 2` on line 120: `if (brickConfig[x].substring(i, i + 1).equals("*"))`. The constructor incorporating `brickConfig` in the only thing I am stuck on. I don't believe I have the pixel spacing between the bricks figured out yet but I'm assuming it will be somewhere in the array creation in this class. `-1` in the brick class translates to an unbreakable brick.

```
public class Level
{

    private int startLeft = 10;

    private int startTop = 10 * 4;

    private Ball levelBall;

    private Paddle levelPaddle;

    private int width;

    private int height;

    private Brick[][] levelStructure = new Brick[5][7];

    private GameState gState;

    public Level(int widthIn, int heightIn)
    {
        width = widthIn; 
        height = heightIn;
        levelBall = new Ball(width / 2, height / 2);
        levelPaddle = new Paddle(0, 420);
    }

    /**Creates a level with a given dimension and specified brick 
     * configuration. The Brick configuration is specified through an 
     * array of String values where each character corresponds to a 
     * single Brick.This array of Strings is guaranteed to contain 5
     *  valid Strings, each of which will have 7 characters.Characters 
     *  in the string will correspond to one value in 
     *  {'*', '0', '1', '2', '3'} where: 
     *  '*' signifies a brick that cannot be broken 
     * '0' signifies a "ghost brick" that is already broken 
     * '1' signifies a brick that requires one hit to break 
     * '2' signifies a brick that requires two hits to break 
     * '3' signifies a brick that requires three hits to break 
     * 
     * Input strings are assumed valid and no error checking is 
     * provided. 
     *
     * Bricks are arranged starting 40 pixels from the top edge of 
     * the screen and 10 pixels from the left edge of the screen. 
     * Bricks should be spaced with 5 pixels between each Brick in 
     * both dimensions. 
     *
     * The Ball will start in the center of the screen, and the 
     * Paddle's top-left edge should be positioned at the left edge 
     * and 20 pixels up from the bottom of the screen.
     *
     * @param widthIn The logical width of the new level in pixels.
     * @param heightIn The logical height of the new level in pixels.
     * @param brickConfig The configuration array specifying the grid of Bricks to use in this new level.
     */
    public Level(int widthIn, int heightIn, java.lang.String[] brickConfig)
    {
        width = widthIn; 
        height = heightIn;
        gState = GameState.PLAYING;



        for (int x = 0; x < levelStructure.length; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < levelStructure[x].length; i++)
            {
                if (brickConfig[x].substring(i, i + 1).equals("*"))
                {
                    levelStructure[x][i] = new Brick(startTop, startLeft, -1);
                }
                else
                {
                    levelStructure[x][i] = new Brick(startTop, startLeft, 
                            Integer.parseInt(brickConfig[x].substring(i, i + 1)));
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @resueman Im getting a `String index out of range: 2` on     `if (brickConfig[x].substring(i, i + 1).equals("*"))`. I probably should've mentioned that

Comment: That suggests that the array contains a string like `"*"`, but you're attempting to access the second character in the `String` (which obviously doesn't exist). With the way you've set it up, the first `String` in the list needs to be 1+ characters long, the second needs to be 2+ characters long, the third needs to be 3+ long, etc. If that's not what you want, then you may not want to use `substring` at all, and just do comparisons directly on the original `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are iterating over the string. i+1 could be the last character + 1 which puts it out of range. Try using string.length